# Backslash (\) still there after escaping apostrophe in Android Studio XML layout file

Tags: xml, android-studio, escaping

From my strings.xml file:

```
<string name="instructions">...users\'...</string>
```

Expected output: *...users'...*

Actual output: *...users/'...*

Everything I read says to escape an apostrophe with a backslash, but this is obviously not working. I know surrounding the text in double quotes would be an easy workaround, but I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's what you're asking for, but I think the solution would be to write `&apos` instead of `\'`. Try that and I hope it fixes the problem you're having. Cheers!

Comment: There is an error when I write &apos in my .xml file.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I forgot to add a ; at the end. You have to add &apos; wherever you want the apostrophe to show. Without the ; there will be an error. Just tried it and it works fine.